# Android Fragment Null pointer exception

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, android-fragmentactivity

I am learning android developing(novice).I want to add a fragment to the mainActivity with a textview and change the text. This code works perfectly:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
//@Nullable
//@Override
TextView textt;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textview)).setText("some text");

    return view;
}

}
```

But this codes invokes null pointer exception:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
//@Nullable
//@Override
TextView textt;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);

    textt =  (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textview);
    return view;
}

public void updateText() {
    textt.setText("some text");
}
}
```

and:

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
//@Nullable
//@Override
View view;
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);

    return view;
}

public void updateText() {

    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textview)).setText("some text");
}
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    Fragment1 frg1 = new Fragment1();
    ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, frg1);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
    frg1.updateText();
}
}
```

**why these codes providing different outcome?**

[my project](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-bloStxhrNCN3dqODN4aGxFYms)

Comment: where is `updateText()` called?

Comment: I have edited the question and added main activity.Please have a look.

Comment: clearly  `frg1.updateText();` is called _before_ the _onCreateView_ lifecycle method is called.. YOu should call the method after you set `textt =  (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textview);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`frg1.updateText();` is called before the onCreateView lifecycle method of your fragment is called.. You should call the method after you set

`textt = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textview);`

```
 View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_fragment1, container, false);

    textt =  (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.textview);
    this.updateText();//here
    return view;
```

Check out [fragment lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html) docs regarding `onCreateView`

> The system calls this when it's time for the fragment to draw its user interface for the first time.

This will happen when fragment is loaded not when it is created in your activity.

Comment: I had this misconception. I was stuck with these problem for more than two day. You made my day.Thank you a lot. :)

Answer (score 1):

Here, the textview is not created when you call the updateText function.

Do such calls inside your fragment. Not on the activity which houses the fragment.

Comment: I had a misconception about fragment lifecycle. Problem solved. Thank you. :)

Comment: Glad to know. Put upvote or mark as answer so others could find it useful.